# Rails STI override model_name in parent class for all subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, routes, sti

I am using STI in a Rails app and in order to not have to define routes for all subclasses, I put the following in each subclass:

```
def self.model_name
  Mapping.model_name
end
```

In the above example, `Mapping` is the parent model name. Example:

```
class UserMapping < Mapping; end
```

Having to put this in each subclass is not very DRY, so I'm looking for a way to set that in the parent somehow, so that each class that inherits from the parent automatically has the model name set as the parent model name.

Perhaps there is even a better way to overcome the routing issue that arises from STI unrelated to setting the `model_name` - I'm open to suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this in your `Mapping` class:

```
class Mapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    super
    def subclass.model_name
      superclass.model_name
    end
  end
end
```

Afterwards, all child classes of `Mapping` will also inherit the parent's `model_name`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to override the `model_name` method in the superclass to return a custom `ActiveModel::Name`:

```rb
class Mapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(base_class)
  end
end
```

By default `model_name` passes the current class as the first argument to `ActiveModel::Name.new`, so each sub-class will receive a different name based on their class. `ActiveRecord` models have a `base_class` method which we can use instead to get the base of a single-table inheritance hierarchy.

If you cared to, you could also name it something completely different. This might be useful when you're trying to transition a model to a new name:

```rb
class Mapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "AnotherMapping")
  end
end
```

[More in the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Name.html#method-c-new)